# ^^ to replace all previous occurrences

Tags: bash, replace

I know that if I have given the command:

```
dothis dothat
```

I can type:

```
^do^dontdo
```

which will give me:

```
dontdothis dothat
```

I want to be able to type something like:

```
^do^dontdo^g
```

to give me:

```
dontdothis dontdothat
```

Is there a native way to do this?  Or is it possible to define this as a function to reference the `!!:gs/do/dontdo` syntax?

Comment: There is no `^` syntax for global, you need to use `!!:gs`. You can't use arguments with an alias, I can't find a way to get `!!` to work properly in a function, and I'm pretty sure you can't use it (that way) in a script, so you're probably stuck with `!!:gs` or horrific history/sed hack.

Comment: @Kevin: I believe your comment qualifies as an answer.

Comment: The whole documentation is here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Using-History-Interactively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builtin `fc` allows to fix a command in history. For instance, to achieve `!! gs/do/dontdo/` with `fc`, type `fc -s do=dontdo`

A solution might be:

```
r() {
    (($# == 2)) || { echo "r needs two args" >&2 ; return 1 ;}
    fc -s "$1"="$2"
}
```

Usage: `r do dontdo`